# White bands on flash

Tags: flash

I'm not a flasher at all. I need to embed a flash into a page, that's all.

However, when the flash is embedded I see two white bands in the left and right side of the flash. The flasher that produced it states that it has not white bands on its sides.

This is the code I used to embed it

```
<div id="vegacer_def_banner"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var so2 = new SWFObject("flash/vegacerdefbanner2.swf", "mymovie", "180", "100", "0", "");
    so2.addParam("wmode", "opaque");
    so2.write("vegacer_def_banner");
</script>
```

As I said, I never used flash and can't figure out where the problem is.

Comment: My best guess is that the `flash` was created with a different aspect ratio (or size in general) than the one you are showing.

Comment: Could depend on the browser. What browser is the flasher using and what browser are you using?

Comment: The same, Firefox. @BenjaminGruenbaum thanks, that's my guess too. So, I should tell the flasher to let me know the actual dims of the flash I assume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.swf` file is likely in dimensions other than `180*100`. You can detect the original size using `stage.width` and `stage.width` as explained [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179653/get-the-embedded-width-height-of-a-flash-player-using-as3).  Then you can either set its width/height dynamically after loading, or change the original dimensions in which you create your `SWFObject`.

Good luck!